# Laravel/Passport - After remigration keys are not usable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-7

**Settings**

- Passport Version: "laravel/passport": "^9.3",
- Laravel Version:  "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
- PHP Version: "php": "^7.2.5",
- Database Driver & Version: MYSQL 8.0.15

#### Description:

I have used [this article](https://dev.to/stefant123/secure-authentication-in-nuxt-spa-with-laravel-as-back-end-19a9) to create fresh API with laravel-passport. After installation I have successfully registered some users. Then after some coding I have needed to add some columns to existing tables. So after adding these columns I have used fresh command to remigrate all database.

`php artisan migrate:fresh --seed`

The operation was successfully and all tables(oauth tables also) have been created. **But after this migration process existing passport grant tokens are not usable.** When I register new User by sending normal AJAX request from web app interface I get this error.

`Undefined property: stdClass::$refresh_token`

I have tried many ways and researched about this issue but only after renewing old client and password keys process worked.

`php artisan passport:install --force`

#### Steps To Reproduce:

After installation passport just install and creating keys and migrate database. So everything will work. Then after remigrate database with command `php artisan migrate:fresh` . Then old keys will not be usable.

Comment: did you do `php artisan passport:keys` ?

Comment: @Skyro682 Yes. Shows this warning - Encryption keys already exist. Use the --force option to overwrite them.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this question is quite old. But we can use Event Listeners to achieve repeated steps.

Under `app\Providers\EventServiceProvider.php` add the following code in boot() method.

**Laravel 9**

```
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Event::listen(CommandFinished::class, function(CommandFinished $event) {
        if($event->command === 'migrate:fresh') {
            Artisan::call('passport:install', [ '--force' => true]);
            echo Artisan::output();
        }
    });
}
```

I found the `Illuminate\Database\Events\MigrationsEnded` not working for my case. But other one, `Illuminate\Console\Events\CommandFinished` trigger on all command executions.

Answer (score -2):

Do this to overwrite the existing keys and it will work

```
php artisan passport:install --force
```

Or you may publish Passport's configuration file using

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=passport-config
```

which will then provide the option to load the encryption keys from your environment variables:

Refer this for detailed instruction https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport

Comment: I have mentioned that this fixes. But I do not want to edit .env every time after fresh migration. This is not solution.

Comment: @WebMan Okay then load your keys from environment to avoid this situation. I've updated my answer check it once

Comment: I have already have these inside .env

PERSONAL_CLIENT_ID=1
PERSONAL_CLIENT_SECRET=

PASSWORD_CLIENT_ID=2
PASSWORD_CLIENT_SECRET=
I have deleted my keys just here . Did u try process as I said ? I guess yours also will not work :)

Comment: I don't think you can load your keys from .env as suggested above - they exceed the 4K character limit